# How to convert date string into UTC string in Python

Tags: python, date

How can I convert string `u'04 Sep 2013'` into `u'2013-09-04 00:00:00+0000'`, and if the first string doesn't come in that form, then return empty string u''?

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the relation between two dates, the format is different and also the value of the date is different, what is the logic behind it

Comment: please check again. I made a typo... or two :)

Comment: Have a look in pythons dateutil and the functions strptime and strftime, which do there types of conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the string into a date object, use datetime.strftime() to output in whatever format you like:

`from datetime import datetime
inDate = "04 Sep 2013"
d = datetime.strptime(inDate, "%d %b %Y")
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

OUTPUT:

`'2013-09-04 00:00:00'`